# Wordpress theme customizing error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a multi language website using Wordpress.

The thing is that my current theme supports customized 'permalink' so plug-ins like wpml and polylang are not working properly in my theme.
So I was thinking that I should write a source code by creating .po files for each languages and getting the po.file when I select the corresponding one on the selectbox in the header. Once selected, it should be maintained even though pages are changed.
I currently use 'appthemes' and each template brings language files using ( 'Read more....', APP_TD ) method.
.po files are like this, #: content.php:46 msgid "Read more...." msgstr " 阅读更多"
can anyone help me please?